# Custom Rake Task aborts on Rails 4.1.5, Ruby 2.1.1p76

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom rake task to evaluate project for Rails Best Practices and Brakeman as follows:

```
namespace :evaluate do
  desc 'Evaluate project for best practices!'
  task :best_practices do
    path = File.expand_path("../../../", __FILE__)
    sh "rails_best_practices #{path}"
  end

  desc 'Evaluate project with brakeman'
  task :brakeman do
    sh "brakeman -q -z"
  end

  desc 'Evaluate everything'
  task :everything => [:brakeman, :best_practices]
end
```

Upon $ rake evaluate:everything the task completes Brakeman successfully but aborts during the rails_best_practices step with the following trace:

```
Command failed with status (14): [rails_best_practices /Users/admin/projects...]
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/admin/projects/bubblin/lib/tasks/security.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with my Gemfile, but unable to pinpoint the issue. What could be causing the 'block in create_shell_runner' issue for this rake task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check if there is no error in `/Users/admin/projects/bubblin/lib/tasks/security.rake:5` as this file is shown in trace.

Comment: Line no. 5 in security.rake is sh "rails_best_practices #{path}". I suppose you're suggesting to exclude the tasks folder from its own rake is it?